# homestead init issue - Homestead has already been initialized

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I'm using homestead 2.0. I had previously installed it but had to remove it and start again. It is telling me that my homestead.yaml file already exists even though it doesn't as when I run homestead edit it tells me that there is no homestead.yaml.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove directory `~/.homestead`. Then run `homestead init`. After that you can edit your Homestead.yaml file.

Comment: Thanks that was the issue.